# GA Real-Time > content > Page showing same url with different page title

Tags: google-analytics, url, google-tag-manager

in realtime >content report
Some pages showing the different title of the same page, e.g. /logos page actual title is
*Free Logo Maker ...*[image]
but its also showing contactus page title for logo

similarly for homepage actual title is
*Try Free Logo Design...*
but its showing another page title on homepage

- i checked filters nothing defined there
- we are using tagamanager for ga implementation

**I noticed this is due to PWA code implementation, somehow content-url being hit as pageview in background**
         UpUp.start({
            'content-url': '/contact',
            'assets': ['css/bootstrap.min.css', 'css/offline.css']
        });

Comment: I'm not sure, if that is connected with your issue, but you seem to run GTM twice on your page with the same container ID. Is that by purpose, or by accident?

Comment: no, i thought the same but i removed all additional events from tagamanger, but still getting this issue(i checked preview only single event being fired on each page)

We have also implemented PWA on our site, should i remove that too, to check if its creating issue?